# create system account for running scheduled scripts?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

how can i create system account for running scheduled scripts? I have some scripts in server schedule which runs automatically by special user credentials, but now i want to create system service or system account for this job. can anyone help me about this?

Comment: this seems to be the way that most folks recommend ... Group Managed Service Accounts Overview | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview

Comment: You can run scheduled tasks using the built in system account.

Comment: @Olaf Using the SYSTEM account is not recommended. If you must use a builtin account with elevated privileges use LOCAL_SERVICE or NETWORK_SERVICE (depending on whether or not the task needs access to network resources). But in general it's a better approach to create a dedicated local account for the service (with the required permissions and privileges).